# Connect JDeveloper application to Oracle Live SQL

Tags: oracle, oracle-adf, jdeveloper

I am new to ADF/JDeveloper. I'd like to configure my ADF Web application to Oracle Live Server, since I'm using a Mac computer, which are not supported by Oracle's database distribution, I have tried to use Oracle VM but it freezes my Mac.

Needs information on database configuration panel are:

- Host name
- JDBBC port
- SID

Answer (score 0):

Oracle does not provide database connection information for the database behind [livesql.oracle.com](https://livesql.oracle.com/). If you want your own cloud database, you should look into setting up an [Oracle Cloud Free Tier](https://www.oracle.com/cloud/free/) database. If you configure your database using the **Always Free** options, you should be able to have your database around for free forever.